# Send info via javascript to dynamically created html page

Tags: javascript, html

Hello really smart people, can I please have some help?

I'm using Articulate Storyline to create an eLearning course and need to capture info entered by users and send it from the course to an html page that they can print.

I've found how to get the info out of the course - however I'm running into issues with the url length (or at least I think that is the problem!)

Here is the javascript that I am using:

```
var player = window.top.GetPlayer();

var header = "Title~~"
var args =(
"Question 1:~~" + 
player.GetVar("Q1") +
"~~Question 2:~~" + 
player.GetVar("Q2") +
"~~Question 3:~~" + 
player.GetVar("Q3") +
"~~Question 4:~~" + 
player.GetVar("Q4") +
"~~Question 5:~~" + 
player.GetVar("Q5") +
"~~Question 6:~~" + 
player.GetVar("Q6") +
"~~Question 7:~~" + 
player.GetVar("Q7") +
"~~Question 8:~~" + 
player.GetVar("Q8") +
"~~Question 9:~~" + 
player.GetVar("Q9")
)

var url = ("print.html?=" + header + args);

window.top.open(url,"_blank","width=800,height=600,menubar=no");
```

It works fine as long as I enter short answers - however if I try and enter 1000+ characters for each question, it breaks and nothing happens.

Ideas on different ways to approach this?

Thank you wonderful people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you SUBMIT data that is more than a few K, you must use POST instead of GET, **e.g. submit a form** which has METHOD="POST" instead of window.open. That would mean you need to change print.html to a server process instead of just html since you cannot post to .html pages

However after looking at your specific issue, you can change your code to this:

`window.open("print.html","_blank","width=800,height=600,menubar=no");`

and in print.html change

```
var url = window.location.href.split('?=');
var urlData = url[1];
var printVars = urlData.split('~~');
```

to

```
var player = opener.top.GetPlayer(); 

var printVars = ["Title"];
for (var i=1;i<=9;i++) {
  printVars.push("Question "+i+":")
  printVars.push(player.GetVar("Q"+i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response - I really appreciate it mplungjan.

Comment: Argh, apparently pressing enter for line breaks in the comments here really isn't a thing! I'm a javascript noob (as I'm sure you can tell) - am I correct in saying that the METHOD="POST" would replace the final line in the javascript above? So it would be METHOD="POST" rather than window.top.open?  I looked in the print.html file but couldn't find any mention of player.GerVar in there - so I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: Thanks for your time mplungjan - I've tried to implement your suggestion but still haven't gotten it working. I'm sure it is something simple that I've missed, but I'll leave it for now and revisit tomorrow when I have a clear head. Would you be interested in helping me set up a template I could use for this in the future (for a fee of course)?

Comment: Thanks, will touch base tomorrow.

Comment: I see this: Perhaps that is useful for you? http://www.articulate.com/support/storyline/how-to-create-certificates-by-customizing-the-reporthtml-file

Comment: Right, that was useful. Please see the update - only tricky bit is to get the GetPlayer to return the data - if there is a quiz with more than 9 questions let me know, I will try to make it more generic once I see the actual quiz

Comment: mplungjan - you are an absolute legend. This works as intended, I'll be in touch.